# random.choice() takes two arguments?

Tags: python, random, arguments

I made a simple mistake in the following die roll function:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice(1,2,3,4,5,6)

print(rollDie())
```

I do know that I need to pass the sequence as a list or tuple, but I was more curious about the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Lecture 5.2 -- stochastic - die roll example.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(rollDie())
  File "Lecture 5.2 -- stochastic - die roll example.py", line 6, in rollDie
    return random.choice(1,2,3,4,5,6)
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

The message says "choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given".

But the documentation indicates only one argument (sequence).  https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

What is the second argument (or seventh in my case)?  Is this the seed (which I have not specified so is being initialised by the clock)?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi closed this question because it was a duplicate.  The cited question was asked 4 years after this one.  Isn't the other question the duplicate?  Doesn't this one contain the better (accepted) answer?

Comment: I did choose the other question as the target because it is more focused and answers are more likely to be useful for people encountering the error (and not doing their due diligence as you did). Generally on closing questions with a newer duplicate target, please see [this meta Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers) which also includes guidance on how to react if you disagree. Feel free to raise this on [meta], for example.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, it seems to me the only thing the other question has going for it is the title.  I could have amended the title if given the chance.  Fine.

Comment: Feel free to still [edit] your question. Duplicate closure is not final, especially for questions that have answers and are upvoted - this question still shows up regularly even for non-logged in users (they would otherwise be redirected straight to the duplicate target). I duplicate-closed multiple questions because searching for a duplicate to a new question turned up *lots* of hits; this does not mean I would oppose re-opening this specific one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`choice()` is a method on the hidden `Random()` instance the `random` module maintains. Because it is a method, it has 2 arguments: `self` and the iterable from which to make a choice.

From the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class.

and the [`random` module source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/random.py#L252-L258):

> ```
> def choice(self, seq):
>     """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
>     try:
>         i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
>     except ValueError:
>         raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
>     return seq[i]
> ```

Comment: Thank you.  I need to think about this some more.  I have just learnt about classes where 'self' features prominently.  Is this the same concept?  That is, random.Random is a class and choice a function within this class or am I completely muddled? Alternatively, how and for what reason would anyone use the 'self' argument?

Comment: @apotheosied: you are not muddled, that's exactly it. `class Random(...):` has `def choice(self, seq):` defined. When you then use `Random().choice(some_sequence)` (so on an *instance* of the class), Python automatically supplies the `self` argument (through a process called *binding*, see the [descriptor howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) if you want to go for a deep-dive).

Answer (score -1):

As per my experience :
random.sample is better solution than random.choice.

Comment: Hi Shalini, it might be useful to elaborate on why.  I am not familiar with random.sample

Answer (score -1):

To fix the code do this:

```
import random
options=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
def rollDie():
      return random.choice(options)


#whenever you use choice you must put the options in a list since choice only takes one argument.

print(rollDie())
```

Answer (score -3):

you must give your value's in the form of a **list** or **tuple**:

**List:**

```
import random

def rollDie():
return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(rollDie())
```

**Tuple:**

```
    import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice((1,2,3,4,5,6))

print(rollDie())
```

This error is because the code thinks that you give each of these numbers as an argument.
the choice is an inbuilt function that randomly selects data from an iterator of data.

Comment: I say in the question "I do know that I need to pass the sequence as a list or tuple, but I was more curious about the following error message.".  The question was not about how one would go about fixing the error (which I demonstrated that I already knew), it was about understanding the arguments to the function.

Comment: I'm so Sorry, I'm new member in this site and I didn't see this part... :3